# how to develop desktop apps for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I don't know if this has been asked before,

I recently installed Ubuntu focal and I'm completely new to it.
I wanted to create some desktop applications for it, but I couldn't find a decent IDE that would help a newbie like me. I found that the easiest way is using glade for GUI design and then doing a lot of coding in the language of your choice from the given options.
Isn't there an IDE like IntelliJ or Visual Studio that can handle all this in one place so we could develop some app without loads of connect this and that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily make GUI desktop applications on ubuntu and other linux based operating systems with the [qt ide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29). it is a reach and user-friendly with great tools to design linux gui software.
features:

1. it's opensource
2. it's light weight
3. cross-platform
4. user-friendly

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't knew this IDE even existed.